# Unable to install npm (ENAMETOOLONG)

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

Trying to run npm commands, I get the following message like the path contained that massive string ("fs: re-evaluating native...").

I've uninstalled and reinstalled node and npm. Uninstalled nvm too.
I can't run anything with npm command.

`Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, mkdir '/Users/myusername/MyRepo/(node:10542) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
(node:10542) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
(node:10542) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
/usr/local'`

In .profile my PATH looks like this:
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin"

Any help appreciated!

Comment: add OS , node version , npm version .

Comment: Mac OSX 10.13.1 High Sierra, node 9.2.0, npm 5.5.1 but I've tried different node versions with nvm. Now uninstalled nvm but because of this breakage I cannot reinstall it.

Comment: What does `nvm current` and `which npm` output?